# How do I concat twp numpy arrays of different dimensions?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to combined two numpy arrays of different dimensions.  They are x = (500,500,500) and y = (500,2).

I have tried `np.append(x,y,axis=0)` and have gotten errors.  I also tried it with various axis values and still do not have anything.  Any advice will be appreciated!

```
>> np.append(x,y,axis=0)
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4528, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Comment: What result are you trying to get by doing this? What would its shape be? What would the contents of each cell be?

Comment: @user2357112 the shape I am trying to get is (500,500,500,2).  I am trying to pass this numpy array into a Keras machine learning model as my X inputs and need the two arrays to be concatted.

Comment: An array of shape `(500, 500, 500, 2)` would have `500*500*500*2` elements. That is more elements than exist in your two input arrays. How should the contents of this new array be created?

Comment: As is usually the case with these kinds of questions, it doesn't sound like you should be concatenating these arrays at all.

Comment: Ahh -- what I want to do is add a column to the end of the X matrix with the values that are in Y.  Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, but that still doesn't make sense to me - adding that extra dimension ("column") to X gives you 500*500*500 extra elements, whereas you only have 500 elements in Y. Do you plan to repeat Y many times to fill this, or something similar?

Comment: Adding a 'column' to the end of `X` would usually be understood as making a (500,500,501) shape array.  Though the expression is clearer when using 2d arrays rather than 3d.  Expending the arrays to 4d adds further ambiguity.